# How to implement an interface for stack

Tags: java, interface, stack

I have this interface for a stack I need to use:

```
public interface StackInterface <E> 
{

public void push (E item);

public E pop();

public E peek();

public String toString();

}
```

And I need to create a linked-based stack class that implements this interface. 
This is for a postfix to infix calculator, so I'm supposed to store type 'char' in this stack. How do I create such a stack?

Comment: _How do I create such a stack?_ By writing code? SO isn't going to write it for you, but when you get stuck feel free to ask about the specific problem you're facing. If you're not sure about how to use a linked list to build a stack there are plenty of books and tutorials available that will teach you how.

Comment: You should note that primitive types (up to the time of this comment) are not permissible as generic types. So instead of `Stack<char>`, you'd have to use the wrapper class for `char`, as such: `Stack<Character>`.

Answer (score 2):

First, your interface isn't generic. Let's fix that

```
public interface StackInterface<E> {
    public void push (E item);
    public E pop();
    public E peek();
}
```

Then you would need to implement it, for a `Character` that should look something like (leaving the actual implementation for you)

```
class CharacterStack implements StackInterface<Character> {
    @Override
    public void push(Character item) {

    }

    @Override
    public Character pop() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Character peek() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The <Character> at the end, and using 'Character' throughout was exactly what I was misunderstanding.